# Why UNIX is not open source?

Tags: licensing

Why Dennis Ritchie created UNIX under BSD licence if he was rooting for open source?

I'm exploring UNIX history and can't understand why it was not open source. I understand that it was developed in Bell Labs, but is that significant reason?

Comment: Could you please explain which part of the BSD License is not "open source". What is your exact issue? Are you possibly confusing the terms "open source" and "copyleft"? Have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commenters are raising a number of issues, all of which are excellent points, so I'll try to pull this together into an answer.

Thompson and Richie [started working on UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix) in 1969, and the first internal release was in 1971.  At this point it ran only on the PDP-11; if you happened to have a PDP-11, you could write off for a copy (presumably to Ken Thompson), and when it arrived, you could run it.  In 1975, Bell Labs realised that software did have value, and [started selling licences to Research UNIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_Unix); prior to that, although you could get a copy, you couldn't get a formal licence, so the question of licence terms is meaningless.

1976 is the date of Bill Gates' [famous plea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/An_Open_Letter_to_Hobbyists) to Altair users to actually pay for his version of BASIC, instead of just giving copies to friends.  Prior to 1975/6, software was much more something that the tiny group of people who were able to improved and shared with the tiny group of people who could use it; if you could, you probably did, and you probably didn't care whether you should.

[BSD Unix was first released](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_Software_Distribution) in 1978, and was *not originally under the BSD licence*, which was itself not published [until 1988](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_licenses).  The modern concept of copyleft probably first appeared in 1985, in the [GNU Manifesto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Manifesto), but even then was [not immediately so named](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft#History).  Free software was not [formally defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Free_Software_Definition) until 1986 and the GNU GPL was [first published](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) in 1989.  *Open Source* as a [near-synonym for free software](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/open-source.html) didn't come into use until 1998.

So hopefully by this point it's clear that UNIX could not have been initially released as "open source" because it arrived years before any of the concepts that underpin it had been articulated, and nearly thirty years before the term itself.  In the excellent words of amon, the question is similar to asking why [Dr. Martin Luther King](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Luther_King_Jr.) didn't publicly support [BLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Lives_Matter).

Comment: thanks a lot, it made a big clarification in my vague unix vision