What is the difference between Open source and "Source available" software?
Just as the title says, I want to know the difference between Open source and "Source available" software. Literally, both the terms mean the same thing, i.e software whose source code is publicly available. But then, how can Source available software be proprietary (closed source)? Also, what are the licenses used for Source available software?
Thanks in advance for your reply.

Have you read (and followed the links on) this site's on topic page? "Open source" is much more specific than "you can see the source". And given what is on-topic here, "what are the licenses used for Source available software" is off-topic here.

For your off-topic question, you can look into the licensing history of some now-open source UNIX software. There is a good Q&A summarising some of the issues here: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13687/why-unix-is-not-open-source

Another notable example is https://doomwiki.org/wiki/Doom_source_code , now GPL but originally was what we would call "source available" now. That wiki also has a copy of the original non-commercial or "educational-use" source license if you want to read it.

@Brandin thanks for the links. And sorry for the off-topic question.

@IsHacker You might also want to read about the headache of open-source ReactOS development in ensuring there's no contribution from Windows Research Kernel that is source-available. If you ever contribute to an open-source project in the future, the mere act of reading source-available codes can be detrimental for everyone involved.

"Literally, both the terms mean the same thing" only under one very specific and narrow interpretation of "open". Is a prison with glass walls "open" or is it still a prison ( albeit a questionable one)?

Note that the source of open source software needn't be publicly available. What matters is that it is available to those to whom the software is available and that users of that software have the right to modify and distribute the source etc. In practice, this almost always means the source code is publicly available, but that's not what makes it open source.

The open source definition is not just about being allowed to read the sourcecode of an application. It is mostly concerned with the right to change and redistribute the software.
With a software that is only "source available", you might be able to look at the sourcecode. But you might not be allowed to:

Change the sourcecode and recompile it, in some cases not even for your personal use.
Redistribute the sourcecode or the compiled application to other people, with or without changes, under the same license conditions under which you received it.
Use the program for any purpose (Non open-source software often has long End-User License Agreements which prohibit certain ways of using the software).
Do any of the above things for money.
Do any of the above things for free.


Note that one of the MOST IMPORTANT aspect of "for any purpose" includes asking people to pay money for it. If you prohibit people from profiting from your code then your license CANNOT be considered open source. There are plenty of non-commercial licenses available such as the various forms of Creative Commons license that are not open source.

Note that the "changing the sourcecode" includes even fixing bugs in the program. On a merely source available program, you could find e.g. that running that program on December will format your disk, but you couldn't change the program to avoid that. On an open source program, you could.
